# How to show $\mathbb E[f(X)]=f(\mu +i\sigma)$ using Cauchy integral formula

Tags: statistics, cauchy-integral-formula

Assume that $C(\mu ,\sigma )$ is the Cauchy distribution with location $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and scale $\sigma >0$ and the density function of $C(\mu ,\sigma)$ is $p(x;(\mu ,\sigma))=\frac{\sigma}{\pi}\frac{1}{(x-\mu)^2 +\sigma^2}$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$. If $\displaystyle\lim_{R\to \infty}\sup_{|z|=R}|f(z)|=0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\epsilon \sup_{|z-a|=\epsilon}|f(z)|=0$, then how can I show using Cauchy integral formula that $\mathbb E[f(X)]=f(\mu +i\sigma)$, when $X$ is a random variable with Cauchy distribution and $f$ is an injective holomorphic function. Thanks in advance.

**My try**: Cauchy integral formula is: $f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz$. By definition, we have
$$\begin{split}
\mathbb E[f(X)]&=\int f(x)\Big( \frac{\sigma}{\pi}\frac{1}{(x-\mu)^2 +\sigma^2}\Big)dx\\
&=\frac{\sigma}{\pi}\int \frac{f(x)}{(x-\mu)^2 +\sigma^2}dx\\
&=\frac{\sigma}{\pi}\int \frac{f(x)}{(x-\mu-i\sigma)(x-\mu+i\sigma)}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int \frac{f(x)}{(x-\mu-i\sigma)}dx-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int \frac{f(x)}{(x-\mu+i\sigma)}dx\\
&=f(\mu +i\sigma)-f(\mu -i\sigma)
\end{split}$$

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hello. Thanks very much. Sure, I'll do it. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper

'Which functions preserve Cauchy laws?'  Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.
Volume 67, 277-286.  Letac, G. (1977)

does not contain exactly the answer to your question but it should be of interest.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.